# Horizontal scroll to left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a web page that sequentially adds various sizes of fixed width panels (`flex: none`) from left to right as the user drills down. When the panels reach (or will overreach) the end of the page I want the first panel (and subsequent panels) to 'scroll' to the left (overflow hidden is acceptable, partial content visible is ok)

Originally aligned left as follows when panel ONE then TWO, etc is added

```
=============================================================
=                                                            =
= -----------  ----------- -----------  -----------          =
= |         |  |         | |         |  |         |          =
= |   ONE   |  |   TWO   | |  THREE  |  |  FOUR   |          =
= |         |  |         | |         |  |         |          =
= -----------  ----------- -----------  -----------          =
=                                                            =
==============================================================
```

Then when FIVE is added it will overreach the end of the page so panel ONE is scrolled out of view (overflow hidden is ok)

```
=============================================================
=                                                           =
=--    -----------  ----------- -----------  -----------    =
=  |   |         |  |         | |         |  |         |    =
=  |   |   TWO   |  |   THREE | |  FOUR   |  |  FIVE   |    =
=  |   |         |  |         | |         |  |         |    =
=--    -----------  ----------- -----------  -----------    =
=                                                           =
=============================================================
```

Conversely, when panel FIVE (or any other) is removed, then ONE should go back into view.

So far I have this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel">
      1 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      2 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      3 of 4
    </div>

  </div>  
</div>
```

```css
.panel-container {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
}

.panel {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: none;
  width:300px;
}
```

I've also tried this:

```css
.panel-container {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: auto;
    right: inherit;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

[My jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettwinters/3w5p6bqt/3/)

My css only works when I don't set the width of the last panel, but then the width expands to fit the remaining space which is not what I want. Prefer a css solution using flex box, but if that's not possible then anything workable would be appreciated

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

oh, of course it was so simple in the end (after a bike ride to clear the mind).

`margin-right: auto;` on the last child. I applied it to all children in case there was some other content there (for example loading spinners, etc to prevent the right margin collapsing)

```css
.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.panel {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

    .panel-container > :last-child {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettwinters/nj7tx0wz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it, tha I know of, is to use JavaScript's .scrollLeft:

https://codepen.io/agakesik/pen/WNrEQdP

```
document.getElementsByClassName('panel-container').scrollLeft = 9999999;
```

Comment: scrollleft is pretty clever, works well in codepen and in console, but for some reason can't get it to work for dynamically injected html from the SPA (blazor) ;(

Answer (score 0):

There's too much in your code. Simplify it.

```css
.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.panel {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel">1 of 4</div>
    <div class="panel">2 of 4</div>
    <div class="panel">3 of 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh40vopf/1/)

Comment: thanks for the shorthand markup, but unfortunately does not solve the question...

Comment: You're right. *"Originally aligned left..."* That part escaped me. Adding `margin-right: auto` is a good solution, like in your answer.